# Converting expression to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to convert the string expression into a list without using built-in functions on Python and regex.

This is the example:

```
"(52^2)+150-(2^2+4+5)"
```

to:

```
["(", "52", "^", "2", ")", "+", "150", "-", "(", "2", "^", "2", "+", "4", "+", "5", ")"]
```

I used `.split()` but the number above 9 is separated.

Comment: Do you have some constraints that prevent you from using regular expressions? Because that's most likely the best way to do it.

Comment: Looks like you want to write a lexer in Python. Without using any regex or built-ins this will be very difficult. Is there any particular reason you have to avoid these? I can also recommend [ply](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) for lexing.

Comment: I am creating a function that is equivalent to eval() and the approach that I used is to convert the expression to to list then evaluate the expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using plain python:

```py
def fn(s):
    buf = ""
    for ch in s:
        if "0" <= ch <= "9":
            buf += ch
        else:
            if buf:
                yield buf
            yield ch
            buf = ""
    if buf:
        yield buf


print(list(fn("(52^2)+150-(2^2+4+5)")))
```

Prints:

```py
['(', '52', '^', '2', ')', '+', '150', '-', '(', '2', '^', '2', '+', '4', '+', '5', ')']
```

Comment: I know that `yield` turns `fn(s)` into a generator, but what is its' added value instead of using `return`?

Comment: But what about if it is a negative number?

Comment: @delux, use next condition `if "0" <= ch <= "9" or (not buf and ch == "-"):` or a bit shorter: `if "0" <= ch <= "9" or buf + ch == "-":`

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I have added your code and it is working but when I have an input like this "((9+3)-2)*5/1" and it becomes `['(', '(', '9', '+', '3', ')', '-2', ')', '*', '5', '/', '1']` how can I fix it? it becomes a negative number after parenthesis.

Comment: @delux, check if "-" is a first symbol in string or there's another sign before it. It's barely possible with generator function, cause you have no access to previous output, but you might use some kind of flag which have to be set after any of signs returned.

Comment: @delux, something like [this](https://tio.run/##bZDPDoIwDMbvPEXtaRWJ/2KiRq4@gUcTg7LJEjKWDQ4@PXYYVNAelvT3tf262kddVGa9ta5tc6lAGeFpHwHHtVGQAmKXeH2/WFfdmJxcIzumKge3ArQB/@oIoRXgAuGQBolf3CFwnXgPyEwepJSlBOnT2FvGoXNAv7yPWenlW5ScDAewO88YshAPLcs8SNEvHbkNvv1nBd59wjq9CsaGH6PIOm1qMRWl9rXo7krdyXy4mEAhdvGakhVNN/MlzqAHPSGagZc2xbNBatsn).

Answer (score 7):

You can do that using [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) like so :

```py
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import tokenize

>>> formula = "(52^2)+150-(2^2+4+5)"
>>> print([token[1] for token in tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO(formula).readline) if token[1]])
['(', '52', '^', '2', ')', '+', '150', '-', '(', '2', '^', '2', '+', '4', '+', '5', ')']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers in the expressions are always integer, you can use the following code:

```py
def to_list(text):
    lst = list(text)
    result = [lst[0]]
    for l in lst[1:]:
        if l.isnumeric() and result[-1].isnumeric():
            result[-1] += l
        else:
            result.append(l)
    return result
```